# What is Flutter's kernel_blob.bin?

Tags: flutter

Every time I do flutter build, I get a file change in

`ios/Flutter/flutter_assets/kernel_blob.bin`

After committing and rebuilding then I get a lot of conflicts because of this file.

What is this file? Should I .gitignore this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The short answer is that this file is a [Dart kernel bytecode](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/pkg/kernel/binary.md) representation of your app's code generated by a compiler in Flutter's toolchain. When your Dart code changes, you should expect the built `kernel_blob.bin` to also change.

In a bit more detail, the `flutter` tool is responsible for managing the build pipeline for your Flutter app. Since your example is an iOS example, I'll describe an iOS build. During a compile via `flutter build`, the tool does the following:

1. **Compile source to Dart kernel bytecode:** the flutter tool locates your app's main entry point (by default `lib/main.dart`) and hands it to the Dart kernel compiler. The kernel compiler traverses the import graph, and emits kernel bytecode to `kernel_blob.bin`.
2. **Compile kernel to ARM assembly**: In AOT builds (profile or release mode), the kernel bytecode is then handed to the `gen_snapshot` tool, which on iOS emits ARM assembly code (we do this twice, once for 32-bit and once for 64-bit).
3. **Compile assembly to an iOS framework**: The assembly code for each bitness is compiled into an iOS shared library (.dylib file) using the `clang` compiler. We then use `lipo` (part of Xcode's toolchain) to merge the two .dylibs into a universal binary and wrap it up as a framework, including verison info, Info.plist, etc. This is emitted as `App.framework`.
4. **Generate the iOS .app bundle**: The native bits of your app are compiled into an iOS .app bundle. Both `App.framework` (your app) and `Flutter.framework` (the Flutter engine/runtime) are bundled into the app's frameworks directory.
5. **Install the app to the device**: The .app file is installed to the connected device and optionally launched.

You should ignore this file (and the rest of the `build` directory) in your `.gitignore`.